# ECO D00 Game for Analysis

Tags: opening, analysis, learning

After long time, I had played ECO D00,- 1.d4 d5 2.e3 . As my precision lags, I was not yet well with Queens Gambit Accepted or Declined variation. For this position 1.d4 d5 2.e3 my Android Chess.com App says Stonewall Attack, I am not much aware what does that first of all, when I checked, its all are different in WIKI for `Stonewall Attack`.

Here I have the complete game embedded for further analysis. I would like to know abt. PIN in this game. Is that arisen because inaccurate moves considering positioning powers or pawn.

Other than PIN I would like general analysis & reviews. Thanks!

Here is the game and PGN,

```
[fen ""]
[Event "Live Chess"]
[Site "Chess.com"]
[Date "2017.02.01"]
[Round "?"]
[White "anandsadasivam"]
[Black "Tudorache951"]
[Result "1-0"]
[ECO "D00"]
[WhiteElo "756"]
[BlackElo "714"]
[TimeControl "600"]
[Termination "anandsadasivam won by checkmate"]
[CurrentPosition "5BQ1/8/3N3R/8/8/3K4/5P1k/8 b - - 4 55"]

1.d4 d5 2.e3 Nc6 3.Qf3 { (+0.37 → -0.81) Inaccuracy. A better move was 3. Nf3. } ( 3.Nf3 e6 4.Be2 Bd6 5.c4 Nf6 6.Bd2 O-O 7.Nc3 b6 ) 3...Nb4 { (-1.00 → -0.16) Inaccuracy. A better move was 3... Nf6. } ( 3...Nf6 4.h3 e5 5.Bb5 Bd6 6.Bxc6+ bxc6 7.Qg3 O-O 8.dxe5 ) 4.Bd3 g6 5.Nh3 { (-0.30 → -0.94) Inaccuracy. A better move was 5. Qe2. } ( 5.Qe2 Nf6 6.Nf3 Nxd3+ 7.cxd3 Bg4 8.Nc3 Bg7 9.O-O O-O ) 5...h6 { (-1.00 → -0.29) Inaccuracy. A better move was 5... Nf6. } ( 5...Nf6 6.Nc3 Bg4 7.Qf4 e6 8.Nb5 Nxd3+ 9.cxd3 Bd6 10.Nxd6+ ) 6.Na3 { (-0.38 → -1.21) Inaccuracy. A better move was 6. Nf4. } ( 6.Nf4 Nf6 7.h3 Nxd3+ 8.Nxd3 Bg7 9.Nc3 Bf5 10.O-O O-O ) 6...Bf5 { (-0.99 → +0.78) Mistake. The best move was 6... Nf6. } ( 6...Nf6 7.Bd2 ) 7.e4 { (+0.82 → -0.52) Mistake. The best move was 7. Bxf5. } ( 7.Bxf5 gxf5 8.Qxf5 Nf6 9.Qf3 e6 10.O-O Rg8 11.Nf4 Bd6 ) 7...Be6 { (-0.20 → +1.05) Inaccuracy. A better move was 7... Nxd3+. } ( 7...Nxd3+ 8.cxd3 ) 8.e5 { (+0.88 → -0.01) Inaccuracy. A better move was 8. Nf4. } ( 8.Nf4 Nxd3+ 9.Qxd3 dxe4 10.Qxe4 Nf6 11.Qxb7 Bd5 12.Nxd5 Qxd5 ) 8...f6 { (+0.23 → +10.58) Blunder. The best move was 8... Nxd3+. } ( 8...Nxd3+ 9.Qxd3 c6 10.Nf4 Bf5 11.Qe2 h5 12.O-O e6 13.Nd3 ) 9.exf6 { (+10.68 → +0.43) Blunder. The best move was 9. Bxg6+. } ( 9.Bxg6+ Bf7 ) 9...Nxf6 { (+0.56 → +3.46) Blunder. The best move was 9... Nxd3+. } ( 9...Nxd3+ 10.Qxd3 ) 10.Nf4 { (+3.28 → +0.36) Blunder. The best move was 10. Bxg6+. } ( 10.Bxg6+ Kd7 11.Nf4 Bg4 12.Qb3 e6 13.f3 Bf5 14.Bxf5 exf5 ) 10...Bg4 { (+0.33 → +2.81) Mistake. The best move was 10... Nxd3+. } ( 10...Nxd3+ 11.Qxd3 Bf5 12.Qb5+ c6 13.Qxb7 Qc8 14.Qb3 Rb8 15.Qe3 ) 11.Qe2 { (+2.74 → -4.24) Blunder. From winning to losing. The best move was 11. Bxg6+. } ( 11.Bxg6+ Kd7 ) 11...Bxe2 12.Kxe2 Ng4 { (-7.22 → -1.70) Blunder. The best move was 12... Nxd3. } ( 12...Nxd3 13.Nxd3 e6 14.h4 Kf7 15.Bf4 Bd6 16.Be5 c6 17.c3 ) 13.h3 { (-2.16 → -6.32) Mistake. The best move was 13. Bxg6+. } ( 13.Bxg6+ Kd7 14.Bf5+ e6 15.Bxe6+ Kc6 16.Bxg4 Bd6 17.g3 Qf6 ) 13...Nf6 { (-6.89 → -3.22) Blunder. The best move was 13... Nxd3. } ( 13...Nxd3 14.Nxd3 Nf6 15.Bf4 c6 16.c3 Qb6 17.f3 Qa6 18.Kd2 ) 14.Bxg6+ Kd7 15.Re1 e6 16.Kf1 Rg8 { (-3.79 → -2.51) Inaccuracy. A better move was 16... Ne4. } ( 16...Ne4 17.c3 Nc6 18.Bf7 Ng5 19.Nxe6 Qf6 20.Nxg5 hxg5 21.Be6+ ) 17.Bd3 { (-2.64 → -5.68) Mistake. The best move was 17. Nxe6. } ( 17.Nxe6 Rxg6 18.Nxd8 Rxd8 19.f3 Bd6 20.g4 Rf8 21.Kg2 c6 ) 17...Nxd3 18.cxd3 Nh5 { (-6.44 → -4.54) Inaccuracy. A better move was 18... c6. } ( 18...c6 19.Nxe6 ) 19.Nxe6 { (-4.70 → -8.49) Inaccuracy. A better move was 19. Nxh5. } ( 19.Nxh5 Qh4 20.Nf4 Bd6 21.g3 Rxg3 22.fxg3 Qxg3 23.Ke2 Bxf4 ) 19...Qe7 { (-8.55 → -0.04) Blunder. The best move was 19... Qf6. } ( 19...Qf6 20.Re5 ) 20.Nc5+ Kd6 { (-0.02 → +1.02) Inaccuracy. A better move was 20... Kc6. } ( 20...Kc6 21.Rxe7 ) 21.Rxe7 Bxe7 22.Bxh6 { (+1.13 → +0.34) Inaccuracy. A better move was 22. g4. } ( 22.g4 Nf6 23.Bf4+ Kc6 24.Rc1 Rac8 25.Be5 Ne8 26.Nc2 Bxc5 ) 22...Rae8 { (+0.12 → +2.33) Mistake. The best move was 22... b6. } ( 22...b6 23.Na6 c6 24.Rc1 Kd7 25.Nc2 Rg6 26.Bd2 Rf8 27.Ne3 ) 23.Nxb7+ { (+2.31 → +1.03) Mistake. The best move was 23. g4. } ( 23.g4 Rh8 24.Bd2 Kc6 25.Rc1 Nf6 26.g5 Rxh3 27.Na6+ Kb6 ) 23...Kc6 24.Nc5 Bxc5 25.dxc5 Kxc5 26.Rc1+ Kd6 { (+1.71 → +3.83) Mistake. The best move was 26... Kb6. } ( 26...Kb6 27.Nc2 Kb7 28.g4 Ng7 29.Nb4 Ne6 30.Kg2 Rh8 31.Bd2 ) 27.Nb5+ Kd7 { (+3.27 → +5.02) Inaccuracy. A better move was 27... Ke7. } ( 27...Ke7 28.Rxc7+ Kf6 29.Bd2 Re7 30.Bc3+ Kf7 31.Nd6+ Ke6 32.Rc6 ) 28.Nxa7 { (+4.62 → +0.88) Blunder. The best move was 28. Rxc7+. } ( 28.Rxc7+ Kd8 29.Rxa7 Rg6 30.Bd2 Re7 31.Ra8+ Kd7 32.Nd4 Rf7 ) 28...Rg6 29.Be3 { (+0.50 → -0.29) Inaccuracy. A better move was 29. Bd2. } ( 29.Bd2 Rb6 30.b4 Ra8 31.Rc5 Rxa7 32.Rxd5+ Rd6 33.Rxh5 Rxa2 ) 29...Rf8 { (-0.67 → +1.70) Blunder. The best move was 29... Ng3+. } ( 29...Ng3+ 30.fxg3 ) 30.Nb5 c6 31.Nd4 c5 { (+1.80 → +3.42) Inaccuracy. A better move was 31... Nf4. } ( 31...Nf4 32.Bxf4 Rxf4 33.Ne2 Ra4 34.a3 Rg8 35.Rc2 Rb8 36.g4 ) 32.Rxc5 Kd6 { (+3.79 → +9.60) Mistake. The best move was 32... Nf4. } ( 32...Nf4 33.Bxf4 ) 33.Nf5+ { (+9.86 → +0.14) Blunder. The best move was 33. Rc6+. } ( 33.Rc6+ Kd7 34.Rxg6 Nf4 35.Rg5 Kd6 36.Rf5 Rxf5 37.Nxf5+ Ke5 ) 33...Ke6 { (+0.07 → +6.10) Blunder. The best move was 33... Rxf5. } ( 33...Rxf5 34.Ra5 Ke5 35.g4 Ng3+ 36.Kg2 Ne2 37.Kf1 Ng3+ 38.Kg2 ) 34.Nd4+ { (+6.34 → +4.59) Inaccuracy. A better move was 34. g4. } ( 34.g4 Nf6 35.Rc6+ Kd7 36.Ra6 Rgg8 37.Ra7+ Kc6 38.Ne7+ Kd6 ) 34...Kd6 { (+4.58 → +10.25) Mistake. The best move was 34... Ke7. } ( 34...Ke7 35.g4 Ng7 36.Rxd5 Ra8 37.a3 Kf7 38.Kg2 Raa6 39.Kg3 ) 35.Nb5+ { (+10.39 → +4.14) Blunder. The best move was 35. Rc6+. } ( 35.Rc6+ Kd7 36.Rxg6 Nf4 37.Rg5 Nxd3 38.Rxd5+ Kc8 39.b3 Nb4 ) 35...Kd7 { (+3.97 → +7.89) Inaccuracy. A better move was 35... Ke6. } ( 35...Ke6 36.Nc7+ Kd6 37.Rc2 Nf4 38.Bc5+ Kxc7 39.Bxf8+ Kd7 40.f3 ) 36.Rc7+ { (+8.08 → +3.99) Blunder. The best move was 36. Rxd5+. } ( 36.Rxd5+ Ke6 37.Rxh5 Rd8 38.Bd4 Rc8 39.g4 Rc1+ 40.Ke2 Kf7 ) 36...Ke8 37.Bc5 Nf4 { (+4.65 → +7.01) Inaccuracy. A better move was 37... Rff6. } ( 37...Rff6 38.Re7+ Kd8 39.Re5 Nf4 40.Be7+ Kd7 41.Bxf6 Rxf6 42.a4 ) 38.Rc8+ Kf7 { (+7.39 → +14.41) Inaccuracy. A better move was 38... Kd7. } ( 38...Kd7 39.Rxf8 Ne6 40.Ba3 Nxf8 41.Bxf8 Ra6 42.a3 Rc6 43.Bg7 ) 39.Rxf8+ Kg7 40.Rxf4 Rc6 41.Bf8+ Kg6 { (+14.83 → +51.78) Inaccuracy. A better move was 41... Kg8. } ( 41...Kg8 42.Nc3 ) 42.h4 { (+53.21 → +13.48) Mistake. The best move was 42. Nc3. } ( 42.Nc3 Ra6 43.Nxd5 Ra5 44.Ne7+ Kg5 45.b4 Rb5 46.a4 Kxf4 ) 42...Rc1+ 43.Ke2 Rc2+ 44.Kf3 Rxb2 45.Nd6 Rxa2 46.g4 Ra3 47.Ke3 { (+58.08 → +18.77) Inaccuracy. A better move was 47. h5+. } ( 47.h5+ Kh7 48.Ke3 Ra8 49.g5 Rd8 50.Be7 Rd7 ) 47...d4+ 48.Kxd4 { (+33.15 → +16.17) Inaccuracy. A better move was 48. Ke4. } ( 48.Ke4 Ra7 49.h5+ Kg5 50.Nf7+ Kh4 51.h6 Kh3 52.h7 Kg2 ) 48...Rxd3+ { (+25.38 → +318.00) Mistake. The best move was 48... Rb3. } ( 48...Rb3 49.h5+ ) 49.Kxd3 Kh7 50.g5 { (Mate in 4 → Mate in 4) Excellent. Faster mate A better move was 50. Nf5. } ( 50.Nf5 Kg8 51.Ne7+ Kh8 52.Rf5 Kh7 53.Rh5# ) 50...Kg6 51.Rf6+ { (Mate in 5 → Mate in 5) Excellent. Faster mate A better move was 51. Ke4. } ( 51.Ke4 Kh7 52.h5 Kh8 53.g6 Kg8 54.Bh6 Kh8 55.Rf8# ) 51...Kh5 52.g6 Kxh4 53.g7 Kh3 54.g8=Q Kh2 55.Rh6#  1-0
```

Here is the fen,

```
[fen "5BQ1/8/3N3R/8/8/3K4/5P1k/8 b - - 4 55"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Stonewall attack refers to a pawn structure with pawns on f4, e3 and d4. If you don't play f4, it should not be called stonewall. If you want to give it a name you could call it closed "Queen's pawn game". In any case looking at this game you should not worry about opening at all, but first and foremost focus on not blundering pieces in one move (and so should your opponent).

> I would like to know abt. PIN in this game.

Do you mean a [pin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pin_(chess))? At which move do you see a pin?

Analysis/comments:

- 3. Qf3 Getting out the queen early makes her prone to attack. Develop your minor pieces (bishop, knight) first. Also on f3 the queen does not do much and takes away that square for development of the knight.
- 5. Nh3 and 6. Na3 You really like putting the knights on the rim, do you? Usually it is better to develop knights towards the center (via c3, f3, d2 or e2) where they have more space and can attack things)
- 7. e4 Here you could have won a pawn after 7 Bxf5 gxf5 8. Qxf5 (tactical motif: *counting*)
- Starting from move 9. you could just take the pawn on g6 with check
- 11. Qe2?? It is good that you realized that your queen was attacked but you should have removed her to somewhere safe like e3 or g3. Also you could still have captured Bxg6+ with check and only after that removed your queen.
- 19. Nxh5 would give you a knight for free
- 20 Nc5+ and 21 Rxe7 Well spotted that you can win the queen!
- 33 Rc6+ (*skewer*) would win the rook on g6; 33 Nf5+?? this knight could just be taken by black 33. ... Rxf5
- 35 Nb5+? Missed your second chance to play 35 Rc6+ winning the rook on g6

Your question suggests that you are concerned about opening theory, which you really should not at this level. During the game you and your opponent blundered like 5 pieces each and whether you play queen's gambit or stonewall attack or whatnot is completely irrelevant in this case.

Most important for you would be to concentrate on not blundering pieces and also to take pieces when allowed to. So at every move check whether something is attacked and whether you attack something which you can capture. Also before making a move make sure that after the move you don't lose material. There are two ways to do this, you can go through the whole board each and every time to look for these things or you can do this incrementally, meaning to look for changes in the position. What I mean by this is that if say your opponent makes a move this will only affect some part of the board, so you only need to look for any changes in that part (and keep in mind all the other potential options which did not change).

Once you blunder fewer pieces you can start studying basic tactics like pin, skewer, double attack (knight and pawn forks) and improve on your strategy, which is not all that bad (for a player at your level), except for somewhat neglecting development of pieces.

Only then should you think of opening theory.

Comment: Your Answer shows much grit.

Comment: @DevAnandSadasivam I totally agree with this answer. You are not at the level where a specific opening will make any difference whatsoever to your game. What you need in order to improve is to look out for hanging pieces/pawns and possible checks. What you need about openings are basic opening principles, and nothing more. You need to learn to spot hanging pawns/pieces, since it's not possible to improve if you can't do this. It is absolutely essential.

Comment: In the Answer he is asking where is the `PIN` & to say 1..12 moves any experienced guy would say abt. opening and what it could progress better. 12..25 may at expertise level. And it is not mandated that there can be improper openings as in first steps. Game developing principles & end game are absolute to, but may depends with well did opening principles, concerning opponents move.

Comment: Could you please tell us what this "PIN" is that you are talking about? Is it an abbreviation for something or is it the pin (small letters) in the chess meaning (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pin_(chess)) or something else?

Comment: @DevAnandSadasivam After some though, I realized that by PIN you could mean the ECO code (D00). Is that what you meant?